# Invalid STRING constant error in Apache Cassandra (using Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cassandra

I'm new to Apache Cassandra (using Python 3) and I'm trying to create a table based on a csv file. Here's how the file looks like this one:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYRS1.jpg (sorry but I don't have enough reputation points to post the image here)

First I create the table

```
query1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1(artist text, title text, \
            length text, sessionId text, itemInSession text, PRIMARY KEY (sessionId, title, artist))"     

session.execute(query1)
```

And then I try to read the file and insert the desired data into the table:

```
file = 'event_datafile_new.csv'

with open(file, encoding = 'utf8') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    next(csvreader) # skip header
    for line in csvreader:
        query = "INSERT INTO table1(artist, title, length, sessionId, itemInSession)"
        query = query + "VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        session.execute(query, (line[0], line[9], line[5], line[8], line[3]))
```

However, I get the follow error:

```
---> 13         session.execute(query, (line[0], line[9], line[5], line[8], line[3]))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so in cassandra.cluster.Session.execute (cassandra/cluster.c:38536)()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so in cassandra.cluster.ResponseFuture.result (cassandra/cluster.c:80834)()

InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid STRING constant (288.9922) for "length" of type float"
```

Even when I tried changing the format of "length" to float - and %s to %f on the INSERT statement - it didn't workout. Does anyone know what might be the issue? Many thanks! :)

Comment: FWIW, it makes sense to change the datatype of length to float. And here in your program the line `query = query + "VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"` you may want to substitute the values and then call `session.execute`.

It may help to print out what values are being received before executing `session.execute` (in case some rows are not being parsed as desired).

Comment: can you execute in `cqlsh` following commands: `use put_your_keyspace_here;` and `describe table1;` ?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure about data conversion in the python CSV module - by default it's string, but can convert to float if some options are specified. can you print `type(line[5])` before executing insert?

Comment: Have you tried to put single "ticks" around the "%s"? Not a python guy, but as these are text elements, text needs single ticks. E.g.:  VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')

Comment: @JimWartnick python driver should add correct quoting if necessary, depending on the type...

Comment: This question is an assignment on the Udacity Data engineering programme.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Whenever you read from a file with csvreader: "Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings No automatic data type conversion is performed unless the QUOTE_NONNUMERIC format option is specified" from: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

with a table defined with types such as:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1(artist text, title text, \
            length double, sessionId int, itemInSession int, PRIMARY KEY (sessionId, title, artist))"
```

If you cast your values to the correct type it should work work. I tried this and it worked.

```
session.execute(query, (line[0], line[9], float(line[5]), int(line[8]), int(line[3])))
```